# Textbox width control in form

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have design form with bootstrap , and the form output is this
[image: I want to extend the last name width to form end]
and the code as below:

```
<form action="/Home/UpdateQuotMaster" class="border border-light" id="frmQuot" method="post" name="frmQuot">
<div class="form-row py-sm-3 mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="">Doc Code</span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="docMaster_sDocCode" name="docMaster.sDocCode" type="text" value="" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" ">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="">Quote Date :</span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="docMaster_sDocCode" name="docMaster.sDocCode" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" ">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="">Valid Date :</span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="docMaster_sDocCode" name="docMaster.sDocCode" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="">First and last name</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" style="width:90px;flex-grow: 0;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" style="width:100% ;flex-grow: 0;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I increase the 100% width of text box of [Last Name]. So the width text box of Last name can be extend into Valid date text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only set `max-width` on the First Name Textbox it should work

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="">First and last name</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" style="max-width:90px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
</div>
```

PS those inputs do not have an ID and Name property.

And this syntax is incorrect `<div class="col-md-4" ">`